# Compile fonts into a single file

Tags: fonts, font-face, typography

I've downloaded `Sansation` fonts from http://www.dafont.com/sansation.font now I want to compile all styles `regular, italic, bold` etc. into a single file and embed this font via css like

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Sansation';
    src: url('Sansation.eot');
    src: url('Sansation.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('Sansation.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Sansation.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('Sansation.svg#BitstreamVeraSerifBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

### Sansation fonts

```
Sansation_Bold.ttf
Sansation_Bold_Italic.ttf
Sansation_Italic.ttf
Sansation_Light.ttf
Sansation_Light_Italic.ttf
Sansation_Regular.ttf
```

I found tools to convert `ttf` font to `eot, woff, svg` but need to compile all styles into a single `ttf` font.

Googled but unfortunately didn't succeed. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

i don't think that's possible...you'll be overwriting each font-style/weight's characters with each successive font...
you can add them all together into a style sheet, so that you only have to name one font-famly in you font-face declarations....is that you are want?